# How to pass data between activities forward and backward, android, kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

Let's say my application has 4 activities (A -> B -> C -> D) when going forward, activity A pass a data value called `category` to activity B and then activity B pass category and also and data value called `level` and both used in activity D to get data from firebase realtime database. but when the user goes back to activity C and tries to go again to D data passed from A (`category`) is now null. so data can't retrieve from firebase. my question is how can I solve this situation.? "I pass data using Intent by putting extras." are there any other ways?

Comment: `are there any other ways?` yes, one activity, several fragments

Comment: How does the user go back from D to C? Using an Intent or using the BACK key? Also, when C launches D is Activity C still in the task stack, or did it call `finish()`?

Comment: user go back with the back key and `finish()` didn't call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use startactivityforresult and set a result intent which includes the data you want to pass back
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shared ViewModel. Viewmodels are lifecycle-aware components. Data in ViewModels does not disappear when activity changes

Save your data (category,level) in ViewModel like this :

```
private val _categoryValue =
    MutableLiveData<CategoryType>()
val categoryValue: 
LiveData<ResponseState<CategoryType> =
    _categoryValue
```

And update your data in activity like this:

```
vm.categoryValue.value = newCategoryValue
```

If you are using binding etc. observe and do stuff with your data like this:

```
vm.deleteFileResponse.observe(this){ category ->
  //Do stuff
 }
```